# I am currently on fire. Can I survive this?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Minecraft, how much damage does fire do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49522/in-minecraft-how-much-damage-does-fire-do)

Usually when I go mining, I accidentally hit some lava and I catch on fire.  Sometimes I 'try swimming in lava' but when I get out of the lava, I am still on fire and dying a slow painful death.   It seems like death is just a matter of time at this point.   If there is no water around to dive into, is there any hope for survival?

Comment: Oh no, don't worry. Your death will be rather quick. Not slow at all. :)

Comment: @RavenDreamer I don't think this is a duplicate.  I don't want to know how much damage fire does, but rather what to do when I am on fire to survive it.

Comment: Stop! Drop! Roll!!

Comment: Go jump in a river!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you carry a bucket of water around (most vets do) you can use the bucket of water to put yourself out.

You can also brew fire resistance potions once your more established which can severly help the situation.

If you have neither of these things, the most you can do is chuck as many of your items to a safe spot before you die to prevent the lava or fire from destroying them upon your death. Note that fire does not ALWAYS kill you, the damage it does can be found in the question murgatroid linked in the comment under my answer.

Comment: The damage fire does is not random: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49522/in-minecraft-how-much-damage-does-fire-do/49527#49527

Comment: Always carry a bucket of water. It's useful for cooling lava into obsidian (so you can't fall into it in the first place), mining near lava (so your diamonds don't drop into lava), and making water ladders to drop long distances without dying.